# Various users in their normal accounts uploading to one channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using youtube data api v3, I wanna know if it's possible in some way to upload videos to a brand account with multiple users.

I already know that it's needed to add members as managers to do this, but they need to choose the brand account in the login if they want to upload the video, and for me that's a problem because i'm using firebase auth based on google session and saving name, email and stuff as my app users, but choosing the brand account it will always be "same user" uploading the videos and not the real one.

Best scenario:
Be able to get a token to the request from the brand account like using the client_id and client_secret in background without google authentication of the user.

Good scenario:
The user is a manager and with his normal account (not the brand he manages) he can upload freely.

Worst scenario:
It's impossible to do this.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to let the users upload the videos on behalf of the manager (will always be "same user" uploading the videos and not the real one)? AFAIK, this is not supported by Youtube API as stated in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35918111/5995040). In this another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41016619/5995040), it talks about letting an admin user access multiple Brand Account (opposite of what you are trying to accomplish). Slashing out the best option, I think it is doable with the good scenario.

Comment: Check this related [post](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/344) regarding access token from Firebase Auth to Youtube Data API.

Comment: @Mr.Rebot thank you, really, thank you, I was going crazy, because of the consent flow in google authentication, what I needed was the implicit that was my best scenario, based on your link in the second comment, I was able to pass my client id and secret, (and cut the concept errors) and get the access key to upload videos.

Comment: Were you able to upload the video like in the process you have described?